# I am going to that corner and turning

Tags: sentence-meaning

Ann must leave Joe and he drove near the embassy.

> "Stop at the next corner, please," said Ann, as they neared the embassy.
>   Joe slowed and stopped the car. He could see the embassy gate up
>   ahead. "I have to leave you now," said Ann without looking at him. "**I
>   am going to that corner and turning.** You must stay in the car and
>   drive away. Promise not to watch me go beyond the corner. Just drive
>   away and leave me, as I leave you."

This is from a simplified novel "Roman Holiday". If "turning" is a noun, aren't "corner" and "turning" the same? If "turning" is a gerund、shouldn't it be "I am going to that corner and turn it.". Could you teach me?

Comment: You should add your description of Ann's movements at that point. The "corner" is a location, and "turning" is going around that corner (turning from the earth's perspective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning is neither a noun nor a gerund: it is a 'present' participle in a progressive construction with conjoined complements:

`(going to that corner 
 I am   -(and 
         (turning.`

Comment: Is it "I am turning" and Is "I am" omitted?

Comment: @YuuichiTam You could think of it like that, but it think it's more useful to think of it as a conjunct, as in "I am running and jumping".

Comment: Thank you. I first thought it was a conjunct like "I am going to that corner and (I am going to) turning.", but I thought it was unnatural. However it makes sense that "I am going to that corner and (I am) turning."